# Get a syntax error when doing a Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

I have written the following code:

```
WITH b AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Core].[dbo].[SalesAccount] 
    WHERE [SalesAccount].[RecordUpdateDate] > 2014-07-15
) 
a AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Core].[dbo].[SalesActivity]
) 
SELECT * 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.SalesAccountSFID = b.SalesAccountSFID
```

I got this basically as a modification of the queries here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-ace-data-science-interviews-sql-b71de212e433

For the life of me, I can't understand why does it throws an error?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: Your Link has a little Error in "The proper way to ex...". There is comma missing between `) a`. But before it does in an other code section..

Comment: CTE's have one big advantage, you can give them names. Don't waste it with names like `b` and `a`. Then it would be better to join with the tables directly..

Comment: Thanks. I added a comment to the answer provided below. Do you guys agree with what the article states though that the advantage is that the query is faster by using a common table expression because it filters out the number of rows on which a join is made

Comment: Please read [mcve] re code questions. Please ask a new question in a new post, not in comments. Use text, not images/links, for text. Make posts self-contained. (So a link is OK here but for post re "faster" use a quote with credit.) PS "Faster" depends on the optimizer & many factors. Research your version of your DBMS. Also DBMS query optimization/implementation generally.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: That link has no idea what they are talking about re query implementation. It's nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just be missing a comma:

```
with b as (
      SELECT *
      FROM [Core].[dbo].[SalesAccount]
      WHERE [SalesAccount].[RecordUpdateDate] > '2014-07-15'
     ),
     a as (
      SELECT *
      FROM [Core].[dbo].[SalesActivity]
     ) 
SELECT *
FROM a INNER JOIN
     b
     on a.SalesAccountSFID = b.SalesAccountSFID;
```

There is no reason to use CTEs for this.  I find this much simpler:

```
SELECT sa.*, sact.*
FROM [Core].[dbo].[SalesAccount] sa INNER JOIN
     [Core].[dbo].[SalesActivity] sact
     on sa.SalesAccountSFID = sact.SalesAccountSFID
WHERE a.RecordUpdateDate > '2014-07-15';
```

Note that I've also put single quotes around the date constant.

Comment: Thank you! The link didn't show the comma so I didn't know it belonged there. I know the other way, it's obviously simpler. The article, however, states that the way with the common table expression is faster though because it filters out before the join rather then after. Would you not agree?

Comment: @mkheifetz . . . In SQL Server, I would imagine that they would have the same query plan.  The second is just shorter and clearer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why do you believe that to be the case?